# Fangate not working anymore, is facebook change SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have many facebook apps working, but 3-4 days ago is not working anymore, they are a simple fangate, here is the code od one:

`require_once "SDK/facebook.php";`
`define('FB_APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');`
`define('FB_SECRET_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');`

`$facebook = new Facebook(array(`
`'appId' => FB_APP_ID,`
`'secret' => FB_SECRET_KEY`
`));`

Can you helpme to fix it, if you know if facebook have made some changes?

Area a new way to do this?

thank you in advance

Comment: This is a real example [https://www.facebook.com/SinergyaSolucionesSV/app_417915514933764]

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $this->config['appid'], 
    'secret' => $this->config['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
));

$data = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$liked = $data['page']['liked'];

if ($liked == "1") {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

it's work for me...

If doesn't work, can you tell me what gives var_dump($data); ?